# Sample Size for categorical variables with given accuracy

Tags: regression, categorical-data, experiment-design, sample-size

I am trying to do a design of experiment to detect a defect (with little information given to me). In order to do that, I need to calculate the sample size. I am not really sure whether my attempt is correct, so any feedback would be much appreciated it.

Variables:

1. Response variable : defect/non defect. The reliability test must accept 99% of the non-defect and at least rejects 50% of defect, under the factors given.
2. Factors to test: pressure (high/low) and temperature (cold, hot, medium).

So all the variables are categorical nominal.

How to calculate sample size for this?

I am new to calculating sample size especially with categorical IV and DV. I was only learning how to do analysis with the given dataset only so far. So any feedback would be very very helpful!
thanks a lot!

---

old post:
To calculate sample size, I am thinking to use the power analysis with chi-square test in R. I will assume one scenario where my power is 90% and the effect size is small. Do you think that would make sense?
Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it

Comment: I don't think Chi-sqaured is the right approach here. Have you thought about logistic regression? You can check the assumptions here: https://towardsdatascience.com/assumptions-of-logistic-regression-clearly-explained-44d85a22b290  And for a general rule of thumb, you can settle for 20 events per variable in your logistic regression model.

Comment: Thank you. I was also thinking to do factorial design with logistic regression before, but still reading more about the hypothesis and assumption.  The aim of experiment in here is to make sure that the factors do not influence the ability to detect. All the products are actually not defect, so should be robust enough with whatever factors.

Comment: By "All the products are actually not defect" do you mean that your dataset has examples of only one class, Y = 0.

Comment: Hi. Thank you! I have updated my information.

Comment: Basically I want to have the test that can accept at least 99% of non-defect, and at rejects least 50% of defect. Additionally, there is device-to-device variability from previous study (but unknown). At first, I thought of doing two experiments, one with all the defects, and another one with non-defects, to achieve that "99% of non-defect". Now I am thinking how to have one experiment instead with 2 class, but still have no idea how to do.